# Qt metaObject->indexOfMethod always return -1

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, moc, qmetaobject

I have one function declared in `Foo` class:

`Q_INVOKABLE void setImageUrl(const QString &imageUrl);`

However I cannot get the function index of that method:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
const QMetaObject* metaObject = foo->metaObject();
QString functionNameWithparameter("setImageUrl(QString)");
int functionIndex = metaObject->indexOfMethod(functionNameWithParameter.toStdString().c_str());

if (functionIndex >= 0) {
 // never the case
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to do what documentation says, using normalizedSignature()?

Comment: @Silicomancer: That means signature and not just the name. That is what he is already doing, although wrongly.

Comment: `normalizedSignature` did the trick somehow. Do you happen to know the difference between my approach and using `normalizedSignature`? I did debug it and there is literally no difference.

Comment: @Niklas: I cannot even reproduce your issue as per my answer.

Comment: @Niklas: I simply respected what the documentation says. If there is no difference maybe some side effect solved your problem? Did you do a complete rebuild or something? Does is stop working if you remove normalizedSignature() now?

Comment: @Silicomancer nope it does not work when I remove `normalizedSignature`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the two compiler errors, your approach seems to be correct. I assume that you had some changes that required to rerun moc, but you have not actually done so. This is the working code for me.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Foo(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent) {}
    Q_INVOKABLE void setImageUrl(const QString &) {}
};

#include "main.moc"

int main()
{
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    const QMetaObject* metaObject = foo->metaObject();
    QString functionNameWithParameter("setImageUrl(QString)");
    qDebug() << metaObject->indexOfMethod(functionNameWithParameter.toStdString().c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
5
```